# Mode expansion using generalised Fourier transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'm looking at a generalised Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2} \left[\dot{\phi}² + \phi \mathcal{D} \phi\right]$, where $\mathcal{D}u_n = -\omega_n²u_n$, where $\left\{ u_n | n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ span an orthogonal basis in $L_2$. I now want to show that I can expand quantum field $\phi(x)$ as follows $$\phi(x) = \sum_n \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega_n}} \left( a_n u_n(x) + a_n^\dagger u^*(x) \right)$$ where $a_n$ is the usual annihilation operator.

My first course of action is to use the Euler-Lagrange equations to obtain a differential equation $$\ddot{\phi} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathcal{D}\phi + \phi \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} (\mathcal{D} \phi)\right)$$

It looks like I need a clever ansatz, but I'm a bit at loss how to include the second term in that. The next step would probably be to do some kind of generalised Fourier transform/eigenfunction expansion in $\left\{ u_n | n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$.

Summarised: How do I treat the second term in the differential equation?

(Some will recognise the problem as exercise 2.1 from di Francescos book on CFT.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Fourier_series

Comment: The Fourier series is a very, very specific case of a much more general thing you can do with orthogonal functions and moreover Fourier analysis can also be viewed as a special case in the group theoretic sense, so you are certainly not limited to complex exponentials.

Comment: Thank you! My main problem arises a bit before that, so I never get that far. I have edited the problem to make it clearer.

Comment: Usually in the Euler-Lagrange equations you take $\phi$ and $D\phi$ as independent. So that second term shouldn’t be there and you can integrate it by parts.

Comment: But for the free scalar field $\mathcal{D} = \partial_x^2 - m^2$ such that $ \frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} ( \mathcal{D} \phi) = - m^2$, so that isn't really true.